# Override the CartItemType in Twig

Tags: php, symfony, sylius

I have a little problem with my new project, I work with Symfony and Sylius and I want to override a buildform in the twig. This is possible ?

The class I want the override is the basic CartItemType (not rework) :

```
class CartItemType extends AbstractResourceType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('quantity', 'integer', array('attr' => array('min' => 1)))
        ;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'sylius_cart_item';
    }
}
```

And my twig code is :

```
<div class="quantity-group">
    {{ form_row(form.quantity, {'attr': {'class': 'quantity'}, 'empty_value': '1', 'value': minQuantity }) }}
</div>
```

And I want to add an other 'min' value in the twig without changing the class, but wathever values put in the form_row (for exemple 'min':4,) this attr has no change and remains "min"=1 in the html code.

Can you help me ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You want to add a second min value in your Twig template ?

Comment: No I want to "cancel" the initial min value and replace it by a custom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't the min value be in the 'attr' array in your twig:

```
<div class="quantity-group">
    {{ form_row(form.quantity, {'attr': {'class': 'quantity', 'min': 4}, 'empty_value': '1', 'value': minQuantity }) }}
</div>
```

Comment: It's work perfectly. I had try out the { } and didn't think to try with the min inside...